# SOAP Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: object, soap

I am getting this error for SOAP API Which I am using to POST and INSert the Data into database I'm Confused whether the error is from myside or API side

An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: SoapFault

Message: Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Back Trace :

Function: __call

this is also one of response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally issue is solved!

Actually the problem was from API Side they changed parameter name and i updated same in my request parameter

Issue was in Parameter  i used to send in XML Request!!